# Paypal was working with signature, now requires client certificate

Tags: paypal, client-certificates, express-checkout

I am integrating PayPal Express Checkout in the Sandbox using SOAP XML. SetExpressCheckout was working properly using a signature for credentials on 9/18/2013. I made no changes to my code or to the web server. I did begin work on Callback using NVP, since no SOAP version of Callback is available. The next day, SetExpressCheckout stopped working. I now get the following error: "80072f0c A certificate is required to complete client authentication" when trying to post to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/

Question 1: Could trying to use NVP Callback have caused PayPal's API server to now require a client certificate rather that a signature?

Question 2: Is there some other explanation for this change in behavior?

Question 3: Should I remove the signature from my sandbox account and request an API certificate instead? (Despite PayPal's recommendation that signatures be used rather than certificates.)

Note: I have tried using my own sandbox signature as well as the generic, "always works", sandbox signature. I have also tried posting to both api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/ and api.sandbox.paypal.com/2.0/ (without -3t). None of these efforts eliminated the error.

Thanks, Chris H

Comment: Can you run "nslookup api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com" from the command line and post what IP it resolves to?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. The API was functional till yesterday, suddenly it stopped working & asking for certificate. However, if we make the GET request via URL in browser, it returns token (NVP params are sent as querystring). nslookup command returned : 23.51.43.42

Comment: The nslookup command returned 23.50.75.42 for me

Comment: I have the same issue, started on 9/20/2013. Till then the calls to https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp worked right. The nslookup command returned 23.50.75.42.

Comment: At least three developers are seeing the same issue. All three report that the issue first occurred on Thursday or Friday last week. This would seem to suggest that the sandbox API is broken. I submitted a question to PayPal technical support but have not yet received a response. Does anyone from PayPal monitor stackOverflow? How do we know if PayPal is aware of this issue? I have a deadline and can't make much progress on my integration without the ability to test.

Comment: Yestarday PayPal support answer to my email that there was a bug on sandbox environment. They say this bug is cleared up, but for me it is still happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you still seeing this issue? 
I am unable to reproduce it even using the IP you got back from nslookup. 
Here my test with 23.51.43.42. I'm having the same positive result with 23.50.75.42

```
curl \
-H "Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com" \
-d "USER=guus_1192700083_biz_api1.paypal.com&PWD=XXXXXXXXXX&SIGNATURE=XXXXXXXXXX&VERSION=108&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=http://www.paypal.com&CANCELURL=http://www.paypal.com&AMT=0.01&PAYMENTACTION=Authorization" \
https://23.51.43.42/nvp -kv

* About to connect() to 23.51.43.42 port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 23.51.43.42...
* 0x8001f188 is at send pipe head!
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x80057568; line 1032 (connection #0)
* Connected to 23.51.43.42 (23.51.43.42) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x80057568; line 1145 (connection #0)
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=CALIFORNIA; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=Partner Support; CN=api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
*        start date: 2013-08-20 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2015-08-21 23:59:59 GMT
*        issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x80057568; line 1164 (connection #0)
> POST /nvp HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Accept: */*
> Host: api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
> Content-Length: 261
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 261 out of 261 bytes
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x80057568; line 1236 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x80057568; line 1352 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x80057568; line 1363 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 133
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< DC: origin2-api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com
< Date: Thu, 03 Oct 2013 20:07:10 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: DC=origin2-api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com; secure
<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x80057568; line 1533 (connection #0)
* Connection #0 to host 23.51.43.42 left intact
TOKEN=EC%2d03T72513NN7526924&TIMESTAMP=2013%2d10%2d03T20%3a07%3a10Z&CORRELATIONID=4776c1624af4e&ACK=Success&VERSION=108&BUILD=7920936
```

Comment: Yes, I'm still having the same issue. In order to confirm that this is indeed an issue with the sandbox environment rather than a problem with my request code, I did the following: I switched the signature from test to live credentials. I then sent a single request to the live PayPal endpoint. There were no errors and I received a successful acknowledgement and a token. This confirms that the problem is with the sandbox environment.

Comment: I can finally reproduce it :-) ----------

2013-10-08 23:38:52 ::1 GET /guido/Test-XML-PayPal-Sandbox.asp |144|80072f0c|A_certificate_is_required_to_complete_client_authentication__ 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:24.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/24.0 500 0 0 149
-----------------------------------
It seems limited to ASP/IIS 

I'm working on it, give me a day or two.
@Viren

Comment: Folks, this should be solved. Could you please try and let me know?
@kalpa

Comment: Nice to hear that Chris! @Viren, is that working for you too? Thanks!